# Erro "JSON não definido"

Tags: json

Olá, tenho um API do facebook que pega as postagens da minha página e mostra em um patcher que eu fiz, ele estava funcionando corretamente, mas a algumas semanas atrás começou a aparecer este erro e as postagens não aparecem mais.

Erro:[image: erro JSON]

Aqui está o código que estou usando.

```
    <html>
    <body bgcolor="#E8D084">
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <body style="overflow-y: hidden">
    </head>
    <body SCROLL="no">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/NextRO685441651600367/timeline/" data-width="413" data-height="290" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="false" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false" data-show-posts="true"></div>
    </body>
    </body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Espero que alguém consiga me ajudar, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Tenta por `type="text/javascript"` em `<script>`. Outra coisa, não é relevante para a pergunta isso, mas por que tanto `body` e `head` em um documento só ? Dá uma revisada nessa estrutura, que pode não resolver teu problema, mas dá uma baita de uma melhorada no que tem.

Comment: Posso estar falando besteira, tente inserir no head uma importação do jquery tipo <script src=js/jquery.js></script>

Comment: Tive o mesmo problema. Pra mim resolveu adicionando uma referencia da livraria JSON.
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js Mais informações: http://www.devcurry.com/2010/12/resolve-json-is-undefined-error-in.html